# Idear un preg_replace

Tags: php

Tengo una variable **$path** que me trae url's dinámicas tipo **archivos/dato/privado/index.php** y necesito crear otras tipo **index.php?sec=dato**.

Para eso he pensado utilizar de esta manera **$path = preg_replace("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/", 'index.php?sec=dato', $path);** para reemplazar todo y solo extraer **'dato'** que es el primer directorio **/dato/**.

```
$path = preg_replace("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/", 'index.php?sec=dato', $path);
echo $path; //Debe de imprimir 'index.php?sec=dato'
```

No sé como crear el patrón para sustituir de la cadena, con expresiones regulares. Agradezco cualquier idea ó ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro si siempre querés extraer la 2da parte del path, pero podes hacer algo así:

```
$string = 'archivos/dato/privado/index.php';
$path = preg_replace('~.+?/(.+?)/.*~', 'index.php?sec=$1', $string);
echo $path;
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/Ro5mLT/1)

Ahora, si van a ser siempre paths, tal vez sea más simple (y fácil de leer) usar directamente explode:

```
$string = 'archivos/dato/privado/index.php';
$path = 'index.php?sec=' . explode('/', $string)[1];
echo $path;
```

Comment: Gracias @azeós por tu ayuda e idea, las dos son válidas, en mi caso es más fácil hacerlo con preg_replace, asi puedo extraer el resultado a mi antojo. Perfecto!